# Where can I rent a suit for a wedding in Tehran, Iran?

Tags: rental, clothing, iran, tehran

I hope to attend a wedding in July there, and I will be travelling for a few weeks beforehand and don't want to lug a suit around, I'd like to rent one while in the city.

However, my google skills are failing me, I keep finding apartment suit(es) coming up in results, despite my spelling.

I considered that it's possible that most of their websites are in Persian and therefore not appearing in results, but if anyone can help find some I'd appreciate it. English sites would be preferable, but I can translate Persian ones if need be.

Comment: @GayotFow probably more towards a three-piece suit, not a tux

Comment: This question is for @MastaBaba, he speaks Persian.

Comment: I don't speak Persian but many words are close to Arabic which I speak, annd after a bit search I found the right terms in Persian (كت وشلوار كرايه) or (كت وشلوات اجاره) which means (suit rental). Start from there, send some emails and see...

Comment: @NeanDerThal It's not `كت وشلوات اجاره` it's `كت وشلوار اجاره`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually really easy and common, it turns out. Pity, as I bought a suit in Canada in advance.

If you come out of Sa'adi metro station, and walk west - between the station and Ferdowsi avenue on both sides, there are a LOT of suit hire places.  Many of them have tuxes as their show pieces in the window, but have regular suit hire too.

I've seen it elsewhere in Tehran, as well as other Iranian cities, but this was the biggest grouping that I found.

Comment: I hope you will forward this on to the NZ Embassy in Tehran!

Answer (score 4):

I live in Iran and I know Persian. To tell "suit rental" you must search:

> اجاره كت و شلوار عروسي تهران
>
> اجاره كت و شلوار مجلسي تهران
>
> كرايه كت و شلوار رسمي تهران

This may help you. Thank you for coming to our country!

Comment: OK so search for كت و شلوار عروسي or كت و شلوار مجلسي or ست كت و شلوار or كت و شلوار رسمي

Comment: I changed the search topics.

Answer (score 1):

It is not customary to rent a suit or a tux in Iran. I think it is very hard to find a rental place and even if you find one, you probably will not like the style and the quality because these places are for people who can't afford a suit. Also, I doubt that any of these places (if there is one) has an online service. You will save a lot of time and effort by taking your suit with you otherwise you will probably end up buying one there.